# What is the relation between the Adiabatic Approximation used in quantum chemistry and the one given in QM textbooks?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, approximations, adiabatic, quantum-chemistry

I am an aspiring quantum chemist and have come across two vastly different versions of the Adiabatic Approximation when studying Quantum Mechanics from the perspective of physics and chemistry respectively.

**The first one** is the one covered in most standard textbooks [Sakurai for example] where it is stated as follows [Sakurai 5.6.10 (2nd Edition)]

The time evolution of the expansion coefficients can be derived as $$\dot{c_{m}}(t)=-c_{m}(t)\langle m;t\lvert\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\lvert m;t\rangle\right]-\sum_{n}c_{n}(t)e^{i(\theta_{n}-\theta_{m})}\frac{\langle m;t\lvert\dot{H}\rvert n;t\rangle}{E_{n}-E_{m}}$$

In the adiabatic approximation, we simply ignore the second term on the right-hand side.

**The second one** is stated in most quantum chemistry textbooks dealing with quantum dynamics of small molecular systems. Here I am writing the version that has been covered in Lucjan Piela's book on quantum chemistry, in the chapter 6, "Seperation of Electronic and Nuclear Motions.". The author has shown that the Schrodinger equation can be written in the following form for a molecular system involving both electronic and nuclear degrees of freedom

$$\left[-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2\mu}\Delta_{\boldsymbol{R}}+E_{l}^{0}(R)+H_{ll}^{'}(R)-E\right]f_{l}=\sum_{k(\neq l)}^{N}\Theta_{lk}f_{k}$$

where $$\Theta_{lk}=\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2\mu}\langle\psi_{l}\lvert\nabla_{\boldsymbol{R}}\psi_{k}\rangle\nabla_{\boldsymbol{R}}+H_{lk}^{'} ,$$ $R$ denotes nuclear coordinates, $$H^{\prime}=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2\mu}\Delta_{\boldsymbol{R}}+H^{\prime\prime}$$ with the first term representing the nuclear kinetic energy and the second term is given by $$H^{\prime\prime}=\left[-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{8\mu}\left(\sum_{i}\nabla_{i}\right)^{2}-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2\mu}\nabla_{\boldsymbol{R}}\sum_{i}\nabla_{i}\right],$$ where $\mu$ is the reduced mass of the two nuclei. In Piela's book, and also in most quantum chemistry literature, the adiabatic approximation is stated as taking off-diagonal elements of $\Theta_{lk}$ to be zero. The symbols not described in the question have their usual meaning and further explanation can be found in the given references.

**What I do not understand** - How does the second (clearly a less abstract version) follow from the definition given in Sakurai, if at all. Are they two different things ? Or can we express the second in the language of the first. If so what are the steps ? Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: In both cases the adiabatic approximation seems to be nothing more than neglecting off-diagonal matrix elements, doesn't it? We can rewrite above equations in abstract terms using a discrete basis $\{|j\rangle\}_j$ and operators $A, B$, such that the dynamics are encoded as $\langle j|A|j\rangle + \sum_{k\neq j}\langle j|B|k\rangle = 0$, and in both cases the adiabatic approximation consists in neglecting the off-diagonal terms, hence simplifying dynamics to $\langle j|A|j\rangle = 0$.